# How to resolve reference not found for git2consul tool

Tags: git, consul

I am using git2consul to sync config files.

I run git2consul with the command and I get error reference not found.

command :

```
./git2consul -config config.json -debug
```

error :

```
INFO[0000] Loaded repository git-consul caller=repository
  INFO[0000] Stopping watcher...       caller=watcher
  INFO[0000] Received finish           caller=watcher
  INFO[0001] Watcher received finish   caller=runner
 ERROR[0001] Runner error              error=reference not found
```

config.json file

```
{
  "repos": [
    {
      "name": "git-consul",
      "url": "https://mygit.com/git-consul",
      "branches" : ["dev"],
      "mount_point":"test/",
      "hooks" : [{"type":"polling","interval":60}],
      "credentials": {
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password"
      },
      "skip_branch_name":true,
      "skip_repo_name":true
    }
  ],
"consul": {"address":"https://myconsul.com","token":"token"}
}
```